# add a method to a prototype

Tags: javascript, oop

I have the following code

```
const humanUtils  = {
  sayRace: function(){
    console.log('Im a '+ this.race);
  }
}

function human() {
  const human = Object.create(humanUtils);
  human.race = 'human';
  return human;
}

const manUtils = Object.create(humanUtils);

function man() {
  const createMan = new human();
  createMan.gender = 'man';
  return createMan
}

function woman() {
    const createWoman = new human();
    createWoman.gender = 'woman';
    return createWoman;
}

const mankind = new human();
const adam = new man();
const eve = new woman();
```

I'd like to add a method to manUtils() which will be only available to man, not to human and woman, such as i can call man.foo().

How can i make the constructor man() to point to manUtils and still accessing humanUtils functions so that i can call `adam.sayRace()` and `adam.foo()` inherited from manUtils ?

i don't want to use the new es6 class neither the traditional prototype reassignment ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance))...if it is possible

Comment: You can use `setPrototypeOf` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf

Comment: On a side note, why don't you want to use the ES6 classes ? If the issue is compatibility, you can use transpilers like Babel.

Comment: @Seblor : i'm just looking at the way basic oop works, it is not production code

Comment: IMO it would be better to use the ES6 classes as they have been the standard for a few years now. OOP through prototype is getting outdated (although not considered deprecated yet)

Comment: I’m also curious about why you don’t use classes. Now you’re jumping through hoops to achieve the exact same effect 

Comment: what is above describes more or less what's happening under the hood of ES6 classes, my interest just goes to a deeper understanding of what i'm doing when using classes ;). @Kokodoko

Comment: Your `man()` should `Object.create(manutils)` just like `human()` does `Object.create(humanutils)`. You should not do `new human` - that create a human, not a man.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason for **not** putting the `race` property in the `humanUtils`? If not, just put the race there and you can make the constructor `man()` to point to `manUtils` and still access humanUtils' functions by writing

```
function man() {
  return Object.create(manUtils)
}
```

And then, if you want to add a method to `manUtils`, simply write `manUtils.fancyNewMethod = yourNewMethod`

## A note on `new`

In your example it makes no sense to use the `new` operator to construct mankind, adam and eve. When you write `new human`, a new object is created  (lets call it `A` for reference) with as prototype `human.prototype` (which is an empty object, since you don't want to reassign `humanUtils` to `human.prototype`) and then `human` is executed with `this` bound to `A`. But inside your `human` constructor you discard `A` and instead create your own object using `Object.create(humanUtils)`.

## Full example

```js
const humanUtils = {
  sayRace() {
    console.log('Im a '+ this.race);
  },
  race: 'human'
}

function human() {
  return Object.create(humanUtils);
}

const manUtils = Object.create(humanUtils, {
  gender: { value: 'man' }
});

function man() {
  return Object.create(manUtils)
}

function woman() {
    const createWoman = new human();
    createWoman.gender = 'woman';
    return createWoman;
}

const mankind = human();
const adam = man();
const eve = woman();

console.log(adam.gender)
adam.sayRace()
console.log('humanUtils isPrototypeOf adam:', humanUtils.isPrototypeOf(adam))
console.log('manUtils isPrototypeOf eve:', manUtils.isPrototypeOf(eve))

manUtils.saySlogan = function() {console.log('men are cool because they have a slogan')}

adam.saySlogan()
```

Comment: well i wanted human() to act as constructor and humanUtils() as a prototype and man being a subclass of human.

Comment: Well, human is a constructor and humanUtils is the prototype in my example. What do you mean by “man being a subclass of human”? I thought you didn’t want classes?

Comment: In the example Adam is constructed by man and it has a prototype chain containing both manUtils and humanUtils. (This is because humanUtils is the prototype of manUtils and manUtils is the prototype of Adam)